# RxAndroid - Kill a Single

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm a beginner with the RxJava. My problem is the next: From the `Presenter` I called a "`Single`" in the background thread, with a `AndroidS.mainThread()` observer. 
When my Screen is onDestroyed then It calls the presenter's `OnViewDestroy`. This is a method for free up memories.

In the Presenter I using `CompositeDisposable`

```
protected CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
```

When my Activity is created, then I call this method: (presenter's method)

```
@Override
    public void loadLibrary() {
        compositeDisposable.add(repository.getLibraryName()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String libraryName) {
                        view.displayLibraryName(libraryName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        view.displayLibraryNameError();
                    }
                }));
    }
```

It works fine. 
But when the activity is `destroyed`, then I clearing the `CompositeDisposable`

```
@Override
public void onViewDestroy() {
    super.onViewDestroy();
    compositeDisposable.clear();
}
```

It's called. But, the `repository.getLibraryName()` still running in the background while it isn't finish. (I see the log is still logging.)

```
@Override
public Single<String> getLibraryName() {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        int i = 0;
        while(i != 55000){
            i++;
            Log.d("T","" + i);
        }
        return "Dummy";
    });
}
```

It stops when `i == 55000`.
There is any option to kill this process? **Because the presenter is dead. Nobody will catch the result.**

Any suggestions? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the code block you produced. Calling `dispose()` or `clear()` on the composite disposable won't stop the underlying thread (it is not possible since like ages) but will try to interrupt it (sends an interrupt signal). Since you don't have anything that can be interrupted (for example, `Thread.sleep(...)`), the thread will keep running. If you want to check whether the current thread is in the interrupted state, you can call [`Thread.interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()) in the loop (or whatever you're really doing).

Now, back to the subscription problem. Keeping the producer going shouldn't cause any troubles for your *view handling* because once you dispose a disposable, it won't receive any values.